# Remove all whitespace from string AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

PurchPackingSlipJournalCreate class -> initHeader method have a line;

**vendPackingSlipJour.PackingSlipId           = purchParmTable.Num;**

but i want when i copy and paste '   FDG   2020     ' (all blanks are tab character) in Num area and click okey, write this value as 'FDG2020' in the PackagingSlipId field of the vendPackingSlipJour table.

I tried -> vendPackingSlipJour.PackingSlipId           = strRem(purchParmTable.Num, " ");
but doesn't work for tab character.

How can i remove all whitespace characters from string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Version 1**

Try the `strAlpha()` function.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-string-run-time-functions#stralpha):

> Copies only the alphanumeric characters from a string.

---

**Version 2**

Because version 1 also deletes allowed hyphens (`-`), you could use `strKeep()`.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-string-run-time-functions#strkeep):

> Builds a string by using only the characters from the first input string that the second input string specifies should be kept.

This will require you to specify *all* desired characters, a rather long list...

---

**Version 3**

Use regular expressions to replace any unwanted characters (defined as "not a wanted character"). This is similar to version 2, but the list of allowed characters can be expressed a lot shorter.

The example below allows alphanumeric characters(`a-z`,`A-Z`,`0-9`), underscores (`_`) and hyphens (`-`). The final value for `newText` is `ABC-12_3`.

```
str badCharacters = @"[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]"; // so NOT an allowed character
str newText = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex::Replace('  ABC-12_3 ', badCharacters, '');
```

---

**Version 4**

If you know the only unwanted characters are tabs (`'\t'`), then you can go hunting for those specifically as well.

```
vendPackingSlipJour.PackingSlipId = strRem(purchParmTable.Num, '\t');
```

Comment: Hi Sander, thanks for your answer but unfortunately our num values have -(hyphen) character sometimes. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Answer updated to show how to handle any remaining unwanted characters.

Comment: no no, hyphens aren't unwanted characters. When i use strAlpha() hyphens removed. Bu i want remove only whitespace characters, not other non alphanumeric characters

Comment: Answer updated with 3 more options. Take your pick.